# Query average with nested subquery

Tags: mysql

I cannot figure out how to calculate the running average per customer up until each month.

I tried to write it in one big query using subqueries, and also joins with no luck

Here is the query I tried with a subquery:

```
SELECT
  date_format(z1.ServiceDate, '%y-%b') as months,
  (
    SELECT
      AVG(cc.total) + 1 AS 'avg'
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          z.Customer_ID,
          COUNT(z.BookingId) 'total'
        from
          Orders z
        where
            YEAR(z.ServiceDate) <= YEAR(z1.months) AND
            MONTH(z.ServiceDate) <= MONTH(z1.months)
        GROUP BY
          z.Customer_ID
      ) cc
  )
from
  Orders z1
GROUP BY
  YEAR(z1.ServiceDate),
  MONTH(z1.ServiceDate)
```

I also tried to join these two queries with no luck:

```
SELECT date_format(Orders.ServiceDate, '%y-%b') from Orders
GROUP BY YEAR(Orders.ServiceDate), month(Orders.ServiceDate)
```

Could not join it with this one:

```
(
SELECT AVG(cc.total) + 1 AS 'avg' FROM (
SELECT Orders.Customer_ID as 'c', 
COUNT(BookingId) 'total' from Orders
where year(Orders.ServiceDate) <= '2019' and month(Orders.ServiceDate)
<= '01'
GROUP BY Orders.Customer_ID
) cc
)
```

where '2019' and '01' would be taken from the first query.

Here is my test schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `BookingId` INT(6) NOT NULL,
  `ServiceDate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `Customer_ID` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BookingId`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `orders` (`BookingId`, `ServiceDate`, `Customer_ID`) VALUES
  ('1', '2019-01-03T12:00:00', '1'),
  ('2', '2019-01-04T12:00:00', '2'),
  ('3', '2019-01-12T12:00:00', '2'),
  ('4', '2019-02-03T12:00:00', '1'),
  ('5', '2019-02-04T12:00:00', '2'),
  ('6', '2019-02-012T12:00:00', '3');
```

I was expecting something like this for all months

```
month    AVG
19-Jan    1.5
19-Feb    2
...
...
```

The dots is there only to show that there is much many more months in my original dataset. 
For January, there was 3 bookings and two Customer_ID's. Therefore the average for bookings up until that month was 1.5. Up until February, There has been 6 bookings, and 3 Customer_IDs. Therefore the new average is 2

Comment: What goes in the dot dot dots?

Comment: Also customer_id is the id of the customer, right? Not a count of customers for that day? Maybe show your arithmetic for those averages.

Comment: The dots were only to show that there is more months in my original dataset.

The Customer_ID is a an ID yes and not a count, yes.

Maybe my goal wasn't clear:
For January, there was 3 bookings and two Customer_ID's. Therefore the average for bookings up until that month was 1.5.
Up until February, There has been 6 bookings, and 3 Customer_IDs. Therefore the new average is 2

Comment: That' the clearest you've been. Edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join a subquery that returns the distinct months to the table and aggregate:

```
SELECT d.month,
  COUNT(o.bookingid) / COUNT(DISTINCT o.customer_id) avg
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM servicedate) yearmonth,
    DATE_FORMAT(servicedate, '%y-%b') month
  FROM orders
) d INNER JOIN orders o
ON EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM o.servicedate) <= d.yearmonth
GROUP BY d.yearmonth, d.month
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5FMng3oAY2GayRZN4SwVQR/1).
Results:

```
| month  | avg |
| ------ | --- |
| 19-Jan | 1.5 |
| 19-Feb | 2   |
```